# Is it possible to show div when hover? Why is my code in css not working?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code, I just copied this from a tutorial and I modified the code for my use, but it didn't turned out on what I wanted, it's not working.
Here is my css:

```css
.project-item h3{
     cursor: pointer;
      }
      #project-contentOne{
     display: none;
      }
      .project-item :hover #project-contentOne{
   display: block;
      }
```

```html
<div class="project-item">
  <h3>University-wide High Spped Information Network</h3>
  <div id="project-contentOne" class="p-content">
    <p>University wide High-Speed Information Network is a 
               component of the 5-year project plan which is the eCLSU. It 
               includes the development, deployment, and acquisition of 
               communication infrastructure.</p>
    <p>This component installs and deploys communication 
               equipment and systems that interconnect the colleges and 
               units within the main campus and the satellite research and 
               laboratory schools and facilities. This infrastructure must 
               be able to support handling large and simultaneous transfer 
               of data between different users across the campus to 
               achieve convenience and efficiency in university 
               operations</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want also to put images in the content so I use the div
Thank you in advance

Comment: no space before hover

Comment: Remove the space before :hover.  Your code should look like this `.project-item:hover{}`.  Then your code should work.

Comment: Thank You, I'm just starting in web development, that kind of mistakes truly helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is small mistake, remove space before :hover and its done, here is working snippet.

```css
.project-item h3{
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #project-contentOne{
    display: none;
  }
  .project-item:hover #project-contentOne{
  display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="project-item">
            <h3>University-wide High Spped Information Network</h3>
            <div id="project-contentOne" class="p-content">
                <p>University wide High-Speed Information Network is a 
                 component of the 5-year project plan which is the eCLSU. It 
                 includes the development, deployment, and acquisition of 
                 communication infrastructure.</p>
                <p>This component installs and deploys communication 
                 equipment and systems that interconnect the colleges and 
                 units within the main campus and the satellite research and 
                 laboratory schools and facilities. This infrastructure must 
                 be able to support handling large and simultaneous transfer 
                 of data between different users across the campus to 
                 achieve convenience and efficiency in university 
                 operations</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```